# Word autocompletion from inside document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, autocorrect, word-2013-preview, microsoft-office-2013

Using office 2013. I'm working on big Word document. There are bunch of common words. The problem is, I wonder if it's possible to suggest words from inside this document while you type (on the fly)? can't find any tutorial or help about this. Even excel has this functionality.  Maybe some plug-in or something like that? any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for was a great feature found in Microsoft Word 2003. For some reason they dropped it in Microsoft Word 2007 only to bring it back in Microsoft Word 2010. I can only assume this feature still remains in Word 2013.

Firstly make sure that **Show AutoComplete suggestions** are enabled:
Click **File** -> **Options** -> **Advanced** -> **Editing Options** -> Tick **Show AutoComplete Suggestions**.

You will need to add your common words as Auto Text in order for them to appear in auto correct:

Highlight the word or phrase you want to add. Let's say this text is "AutoComplete".

1. Click the **Insert** menu.
2. Choose **Quick Parts**.
3. Click **AutoText** and from the drop down menu select **Save
   Selection to AutoText Gallery**.
4. Give it a name, this will be the first few letters you want to type
   in order for Microsoft Word to suggest the saved text instead.
   Normally you will make this the same as the text you are saving. You
   should be able to leave the rest of the options as they are.
5. Press **OK** to finish.

Now when you want to write out the word "AutoComplete" you can just type "auto" and a little pop up bubble will show you the full word and ask to press enter if you want to insert it. Note that you need to write at least the first four letters in order for auto complete to popup.

Comment: I think the OP was asking for autocomplete not on a predefined set of words, but for any word present in the document

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Word 2013... (I mean, I have added item to //Auto Text Gallery// and I can click to insert it into text, but the autocorrection feature is not working. And the //Advanced Setting...// is checked out...

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly what you describe, but possibly useful: this macro will autocomplete the current word using the spellcheck dictionary:

```vb
Public Sub Autocomplete()

    Dim lastWord As Range
    Set lastWord = Selection.Previous(WdUnits.wdWord)

    On Error Resume Next
    lastWord.Text = lastWord.GetSpellingSuggestions.Item(1).Name
    On Error GoTo 0
    lastWord.InsertAfter " "

    Selection.Move WdUnits.wdWord, 1

End Sub
```

I assigned it the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut, so if I type

```
The quick brown fox jmpd|
```

... and run the macro, it gets autocompleted to

```
The quick brown fox jumped |
```

(Note position of cursor and inserted space)

Comment: Definitely a good idea; I came to this thread to find a way to force MS Word(2022) to do suggestions like in ordinary software IDEs(Eclipse, VSCode etc). However, they rotate their suggestions with this button because sometimes the first one isn't necessarily the correct one. Thank you

Comment: Btw, me too added and started using this now on.

Comment: @b.g. You're welcome, glad it's useful. Agreed I have since improved this code so it gives all suggestions in a little menu you can go though with arrow keys and press enter on the one you want. Unfortunately I lost this on an old laptop but I may be able to recreate it if needed