# Autocorrect in MS word / Windows environment

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, autocorrect

MS Word does some autocorrecting on common spelling mistakes (e.g. "withh") but simply does a red underlining on some other words (e.g. "Akwardd"). For the latter cases, one has to right click the word, and select one of the suggestions that pop up. As nearly always the top suggestion is the right one, I was wondering whether one can tweak / adjust autocorrect that for "red-underlined" words MS Word / Outlook automatically selects the top-entry / makes an educated guess?

Many thanks in advance, W

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word autocompletion from inside document](http://superuser.com/questions/519884/word-autocompletion-from-inside-document)

Comment: This only covers autocorrect suggestions from inside the document - no? I am more looking for something that automatically chooses the most probably suggestion (rather than having me right-click and select....). Thanks

Comment: @Wouter, The macro from [autocorrect for fat fingers ms word](http://superuser.com/questions/516137/autocorrect-for-fat-fingers-ms-word) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: That macro is exactly what i am looking for. my only remaining question: The macro works perfectly in Word, but gives an error in Outlook (probably because there is a different way to refer to the range of text / the body of the email) in VBA. Does anyone know how to tweak the macro? per below:

Sub AutoSpellCheck()
    Dim oSE As Range
    Dim oSC
    For Each oSE In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
        Set oSC = oSE.GetSpellingSuggestions
        If oSC.Count > 0 Then
        oSE.Text = oSC(1)
        End If
    Next oSE
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W -

1. You'll need to have added the Microsoft Word Reference Library.  In the VBA editor go to Tools-->References and check the box next to the Microsoft Word Object Library.  Then use this code.
2. Here is the adapted code:

   > Sub AutoSpellCheck()
   >       Dim oSE As Word.Range
   >       Dim oSC
   >
   > ```
   > With ActiveInspector
   >     If .IsWordMail And .EditorType = olEditorWord Then
   >         For Each oSE In .WordEditor.Range.SpellingErrors
   >             Set oSC = oSE.GetSpellingSuggestions
   >             If oSC.Count > 0 Then
   >             oSE.Text = oSC(1)
   >             End If
   >         Next oSE
   >     End If
   > End With
   > ```
   >
   > End Sub

   - S