# MS Word autocomplete like notepad++ or MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-word, autocomplete

I'm writing a big document in Microsoft Word 2013, and there are **many common words**. So I have to retype many words again and again. I know that there is a [way](https://superuser.com/questions/519884/word-autocompletion-from-inside-document) to add words to the **AutoComplete list** but it's boring to add every word in that list. Is there any better way to suggest words from inside a document while you type (automatically, without any additional work)? Just like **Notepad++** suggestions when you start to type something that exists in the document.